# Automatically bind interfaces using AutoFac

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, autofac

I have some classes like UserQuery, CustomerQuery implementing interfaces like IUserQuery, ICustomerQuery respectively. In my binding configuration I need to bind every interface with the respectively query:

```
builder.RegisterType<UserQuery>().As<IUserQuery>().InstancePerRequest();
builder.RegisterType<CustomerQuery>().As<ICustomerQuery>().InstancePerRequest();
```

This is working pretty fine, but I was wondering if there is a way to make a convention-based binding in place of binding every single classe XXX[Query] -> [I]XXX[Query].

I'm using AutoFac as my DI container.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I'm not a AutoFac experienced user. However after some research a tested the code below with success:

```
var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

builder
    .RegisterAssemblyTypes(assembly)
    .AssignableTo<IQuery>()
    .AsImplementedInterfaces()
    .InstancePerRequest();
```

The IQuery interface above is just a tag interface that should be inherited from every query interface that you have. Using your example:

Interfaces

```
IUserQuery: IQuery
ICustomerQuery: IQuery
```

Classes

```
UserQuery: IUserQuery
CustomerQuery: CustomerQuery
```

Comment: This is a clean way. But It is a common pratice to have an empty interface?

Comment: @Matt yes, it is a common partice to have an empty marker interface. So if you own your IUserQuery and ICustomerQuery you can and definitely  should use a marker interface which makes the container registration cleaner. But sometimes you cannot have this option when you implementing third party interfaces which you cannot change.

Comment: There are a couple of patterns that you can research that illustrates the use of empty interfaces (I remember the Marker pattern right now). I'm particulary comfortable with empty interfaces, if there is a purpose of course.

Comment: Note that if you're using FxCop they'll nail you on marker interfaces. They'll recommend using attributes (and I do, too) so the metadata (the stuff you're querying on) stays metadata. You can use a .Where() clause to query for the custom attributes rather than using AssignableTo<T>.

Answer (score 11):

You need to use the [assembly scanning feature](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/Scanning) of Autofac.

If your interfaces or your implementations are sharing a base class (e.g `QueryBase`) or a base interface (e.g. `IQuery`) then you can use the convince methods for the registration like: `AssignableTo<>`, etc. see [gustavodidomenico's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14604014/872395) answer.

However sometimes you can't have a common base interface/class in that case you can use the `Where` method where you can have any custom logic for detecting which classes should be registered and how.

In that case your registration should roughly look like this:

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(yourAssembly)
       .Where(t => t.IsClass && t.Name.EndsWith("Query"))
       .As(t => t.GetInterfaces().Single(i => i.Name.EndsWith(t.Name)));
```

It will register all the types from a given assembly which name ends with `"Query"` with the matching interface, so it will register `SomeNiceQuery` with the interface `ISomeNiceQuery`

Comment: Great info, but the condition `Single(i => i.Name.EndsWith(t.Name))` allows registering `Sample` as `ISomethingSample`.  To be more exact and only allow `ISample`, something like `Single(i => i.Name == "I" + t.Name)` or `Single(i => i.Name.Length == t.Name.Length + 1 && i.Name.EndsWith(t.Name))` would work.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can just register each type as either it's first implemented interface or it's own self.

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(new[] { Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(IUserQuery))})
        .Where(x=> x.IsClass && x.Name.EndsWith("Query"))
        .As(t => t.GetInterfaces().Any() ? t.GetInterfaces()[0] : t);
```